# Laravel: N to N (mysql) relation using Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I got 4 tables:

```
// Table countries
+----+------+
| Id | Name |
+----+------+
|  1 | USA  |
|  2 | GB   |
+----+------+

// Table platforms
+----+---------+
| Id |  Name   |
+----+---------+
|  1 | Windows |
|  2 | Linux   |
+----+---------+

// Table users
+----+-------+------------+-------------+
| Id | Name  | country_id | platform_id |
+----+-------+------------+-------------+
|  1 | Admin |          1 |           1 |
|  2 | Test  |          2 |           1 |
+----+-------+------------+-------------+

// Table posts
+----+-----------+------------+-------------+---------+
| Id |   Title   | country_id | platform_id | user_id |
+----+-----------+------------+-------------+---------+
|  1 | TestPost1 |          2 |           1 | 1       |
|  2 | TestPost2 |          2 |           2 | null    |
+----+-----------+------------+-------------+---------+
```

The database should be able to implement the following relations:

- User **(N) <-> (N)** Platform
- User **(N) <-> (N)** Country
- User **(0..1) <-> (N)** Post
- Post **(N) <-> (N)** Country
- Post **(N) <-> (1)** Platform

So now I tried to implement these relations following [Laravel Eloquent ORM](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships) documentation:

```
  // Country.php
  public function posts()
  {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post');
  }

  public function users()
  {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
  }

  // Platform.php
  public function users()
  {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
  }

  public function posts()
  {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post');
  }

  // User.php
  public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }

    public function countries()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Country');
    }

    public function platforms()
    {
          return $this->hasMany('App\Platform');
    }

  // Post.php
  public function countries()
  {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Country');
  }

  public function platforms()
  {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
  }

  public function user()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
  }
```

But now I am confused, as I thought the way to implement N to N relations in mysql is to add a third table to db, for example like that:

```
// Table CountryUserRelations to implement User (N) <-> (N) Country
+----+------------+---------+
| Id | country_id | user_id |
+----+------------+---------+
|  1 |          1 |       1 |
|  2 |          2 |       1 |
|  3 |          1 |       2 |
|  4 |          2 |       2 |
+----+------------+---------+
```

But how does Eloquent ORM handle the rules inside my model? Will it keep the N to N relations without having to add a relations table? Or am I missing something or misunderstanding the Eloquent ORM Relations concept?

Comment: The table should be named `country_user`. No file is required. Laravel looks for the singular names separted by an underscore organized alphabetically.

Comment: So I will need to add this `country_user` table (instead of CountryUserRelations ) manually or with `php artisan make:migration create_country_user_table`? Right now I created Models with `php artisan make:model User` and table shemas with  `php artisan make:migration create_users_table`.  Will the relations be added to this table automatically if I use the Eloquent ORM syntax ?

Comment: Yes, you would make the table with the migrate method. No, the relationship will not be automagically created. You will still need to do `$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just joined stackoverflow so I do not have enough credit to comment so I will leave an asnwer here.

First of all please correct your relationship definition.

in User Model:( you have mistake here)

```
public function countries(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Country::class);
}
```

and in your Country Model:

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

second you need to create `country_user` table using:

```
php artisan make:migration create_country_user_table
```

after it you need to complete your table:

```
Schema::create('country_user', function (Blueprint $table){
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('country_id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
    $table->foreign('country_id')->references('id')->on('countries');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't I define  `Many Through` or `Polymorphic` relations? The documentation says "Polymorphic relations allow a model to belong to more than one other model on a single association. " Is this the situationn for platform table? As a post has max one platform but a user as much as he likes. But both using the same data. Or will I need `platform_user`, `platform_post`, `country_user` and `country_post`?

Comment: Many Trough is a different thing. Suppose a `user` has many `posts` and a `Post` has many `comments`, then `user has many comments trough post ` . For Polymorphic relations there is a different story also. Suppose that in your application you have a model named as `Like` a user can like a `comment` or a `post`. So a `Like` belongsTo a `Comment` or a `Post` but not both of them. Here we use polymorphic to define relations in a single table. Please let me know for any possible question.

Comment: Okay thanks. I managed to set it up correctly with the additional tables storing the relations, and corresponding definitions inside the models.